# Rails to_json including association with limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, to-json

I am rendering one record with with association like below

```
render :json => Scheme.where("id=?", params[:id]).first
                      .to_json(:include => { :navs => { :only => [:schemeCode,:navDate,:navValue] }})
```

**Associations**

```
Scheme has_many   navs
Nav    belongs_to scheme
```

I need to render only last record in Nav , but above will print all the navs since its one to many. I tried :limit => 1 and ordering it in desc , buts limit itself not working.Any help will be appreciated.

```
render :json => Scheme.where("id=?", params[:id]).first
                      .to_json(:include => { :navs => { :only => [:schemeCode,:navDate,:navValue], :limit => 1 }})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you're creating a complicated json format, try `gem 'jbuilder'` introduced in [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?autoplay=true)  to leave the structure to view.

   In your `show.json.jbuilder` view, make it something like:

   `@scheme = Scheme.find(params[:id])
   json.scheme @scheme.as_json
   json.extract! @scheme.navs.last, :schemeCode, :navDate, :navValue`

   which will render the data in json format as well as keep your controller clean & neat.
2. The use of `Scheme.where("id=?", params[:id]).first` in your code can be shortened as `Scheme.find(params[:id])` if your `id` is unique.

Comment: Thanks for quick response , whether JBuilder handles eager load ?

Comment: jBuilder is only responsible for building view template. I recommend it because your logic in building the json format will make the code a little complicated. I think eager load will call everything belongs to the `Scheme` if you use `include()` and the association is `has_many`